# get certain word from string that located between undercore,

Tags: python, string

This is one of the string that I got:

```
str ='_Name_ created _coordinates_ so that _CITIZENS_ would learn _colonisation_.'
```

what I want:

```
['Name', 'coordinates','CITIZENS','colonisation']
```

I'm trying to get word in string such as Name, coordinate, citizens, colonisation with their original case.

I tried split method to remove underscores and make them individual word. 
,but it did not work well.

How can I do this?

Comment: Side note - it's a bad idea to use `str` as a variable name - you'll override the built-in string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use a regular expression for that:

```
import re

text ='_Name_ created _coordinates_ so that _CITIZENS_ would learn _colonisation_.'

re.findall('_(\w*)_', text)
```

Note *str* is a built python function, don't use for variable names

Answer (score 0):

A regex should do the trick:

```py
import re
s = '_Name_ created _coordinates_ so that _CITIZENS_ would learn _colonisation_.'
result = re.findall('_(\w+)_', s)
```